# delete rows based on type of previous rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to delete rows based on a type of previous rows. If my data.frame looks like:

```
|Date       |Time     | Type            | Gross | Sender_email      |  Receiver_email |
|2018.07.12 |12:45:13 | Website Payment | 30    | aaa@customer.com  |  admin@site.com |
|2018.07.21 |16:19:34 | Website Payment | 30    | bbb@customer.com  |  admin@site.com |
|2018.07.22 |18:21:17 | Payment Refund  | -30   | admin@site.com    |  bbb@custom.com |
|2018.07.24 |07:10:00 | Website Payment | 30    | bbb@customer.com  |  admin@site.com |
|2018.08.17 |15:17:40 | Website Payment | 30    | ccc@custom.com    |  admin@site.com |
```

I'd like to delete the refunded transactions.

```
|Date       |Time     | Type            | Gross | Sender_email      |  Receiver_email |
|2018.07.12 |12:45:13 | Website Payment | 30    | aaa@customer.com  |  admin@site.com |
|2018.07.24 |07:10:00 | Website Payment | 30    | bbb@customer.com  |  admin@site.com |
|2018.08.17 |15:17:40 | Website Payment | 30    | ccc@custom.com    |  admin@site.com |
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If there can be other lines between payment and refund, the only way to sort it out is if you have a payment ID that both payment and refund lines would share. If there is no ID, well, is it the case that sender email of payment line should correspond to the receiver email of the refund line? But there can be several payments with the same email, so one should at least check for the sum as well. (The "gross" column?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
i1 <- grep('Refund', df1$Type)
i2 <- c(i1, i1-1)
df1[setdiff(seq_len(nrow(df1)), i2),]
#        Date     Time            Type Gross      Sender_email Receiver_email
#1 2018.07.12 12:45:13 Website Payment    30  aaa@customer.com admin@site.com
#4 2018.07.24 07:10:00 Website Payment    30 bbb@@customer.com admin@site.com
#5 2018.08.17 15:17:40 Website Payment    30    ccc@custom.com admin@site.com
```

#### Update

If there are other lines between payment and refund

```
i1 <- grep('Refund', df1$Type)
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(i, j) {
       x <- df1[i:j, ]
       i2 <- grep('Website Payment', x$Type)
       x[setdiff(rownames(x), c(j, i2)), ] }, c(1, i1[-length(i1)] + 1), i1))
```

Comment: didn't understand why the second row is missing in the expected output of OP :-(

Comment: Thank you! Unlike the above sample, What if there are another lines between payment and refund?

Comment: Yes, I know. Your answer is very clear and simple, but I was wondering how to use it in a more general situation. :)

Comment: Considering this matter further, I can use your solution at any time, using extraction and sorting. Thank you.

Comment: @Mimi If you can update your post with the relevant example, it would be helpful

Comment: @lebatsnok  If the question is to the OP, please post it under his/her post

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution which may not be elegant and fast enough.
In your example, you can firstly search where the refund happens, then find who refunded, and finally delete these rows.
The code might be like this:

```
delete_refund=function(transaction_matrix){

  #find in which row refund happens
  index_refund=which(transaction_matrix[ , "Gross"]<0);

  #find who receive refund
  refunded=transaction_matrix[index_refund, "Receiver_email"];

  #for each one refunds, find what they purchase before refund
  all_refund_purchase=vector();
  for (row in index_refund) {
    one_purchase=which((transaction_matrix[1:row,"Gross"]==
      abs(transaction_matrix[row,"Gross"])) &                
      (transaction_matrix[1:row,"Sender_email"]==
      transaction_matrix[row,"Receiver_email"]));
    #one may buy several things at the same value and refund part of them, so length of one_purchase may be greater than 1
    one_purchase=one_purchase[!(one_purchase %in% all_refund_purchase)];
    #one may has many refunds, record those which haven't been captured in all_refund_purchase
    all_refund_purchase=c(all_refund_purchase, 
      one_purchase[length(one_purchase)])
    #when some one bought several things at the same value
  }

  return(transaction_matrix[c(-index_refund, -all_refund_purchase), ]);
}
```

Due to the lack of data sample,  I tested it at a simple example I created.

```
df=data.frame(date=1:4, Gross=c(30,30,-30,30), 
    Sender_email=c('bbb@customer.com','ccc@customer.com',
      'admin@site.com','bbb@customer.com'),
    Receiver_email=c('admin@site.com','admin@site.com',
      'bbb@customer.com','admin@site.com'), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE);

  date Gross     Sender_email   Receiver_email
1    1    30 bbb@customer.com   admin@site.com
2    2    30 ccc@customer.com   admin@site.com
3    3   -30   admin@site.com bbb@customer.com
4    4    30 bbb@customer.com   admin@site.com
```

The result is

```
  date Gross     Sender_email Receiver_email
2    2    30 ccc@customer.com admin@site.com
4    4    30 bbb@customer.com admin@site.com
```

Which satisfies the poster's needs.

Comment: I think there is a little mistake in your code.   Both  '#delete rows of refunding' and '#delete rows of those who receive refund pays' are use "neat_matrix". So the refunding code(Gross>=0) is invalidated.

Comment: @Mimi sorry to make that mistake, i have reversed the code.

Comment: @Mimi however I still have some problems i have not realized before. I noticed that in your data I see both `bbb@@customer.com` with double @ and `bbb@customer.com`. I am a little confused.

Comment: Oh, It's a typo. I'm so sorry. My data was not clear, so your code doesn't make the results I expect.. According to your code, the transaction details of the bbb@customer.com'  are deleted. The person(bbb) purchased an item and then refunded it, and then repurchased it again.

Comment: @Mimi I've reversed the code again and did a basic test, it should be what you expect now, although it looks a little complex.